# Missing lib/native/include/ruby/ruby.h and other header files in JRuby 1.7.13

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I am trying to installing ORI8 gems on JRuby 1.7.13 on Windows.

I am getting an error that states:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-oci8-2.1.7.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.

mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at PATH_OF_JRUBY_installation/lib/native/include/ruby/ruby.h
```

I have checked in the `PATH_OF_JRUBY_installation/lib` folder and there is no native folder and sub folders.

How can I resolve the above problem?

Comment: C extensions don't work with jruby (at least not without a ton of caveats)

Comment: What Frederick said. C extension support is due to be removed soon. For now, though, you might try setting `JRUBY_OPTS='-Xcext.enabled=true'` to see if your extension is one that actually works.